# Reserve space between elements

Tags: css

I have a set of  elements placed one after another. If user clicks an element, 1px width border is set to it. As result other img elements are shifted.

How can I reserve 1px width space around every img element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `margin` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/margin))

```
margin: 1px;
```

or set the `border-color` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-color)) to `transparent` and just switch the color

```
border-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 2):

when you add the border you can add `margin: -1px;` to the element too (make sure you reverse the process properly when taking the border off)

Alternatively give all `border: 1px solid transparent` (think they all support that these days) then you just need change the border colour. You could tinker with `border-color: rgba(222,0,0,0);` and then `rgba(222,0,0,1)` for the active element, where a is the transparency. However, `rgba` is not very well supported in IE atm.